# segmentation fault: erase function in vectors

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segfault specially after taking in `s` and `e`.

I have tried a lot to find the error but just couldn't ! please help !

Basically, I am trying to delete element at position `pos` and then displaying the vector, then I am deleting all elements in position range `(s, e)`, `s` inclusive and `e` exclusive.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int n;
    vector <int> v;

    cin >> n;
    int ele;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> ele;
        v.push_back(ele);
    } 

    int pos;
    int s, e;
    cin >> pos;

    v.erase(v.begin()+pos-1);
    for(int c: v)
    {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> e;

    v.erase(v.begin() + s - 1, v.end() + e - 1);
    for(int c: v)
    {
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + s - 1, v.end() + e - 1);
```

Should be:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + s - 1, v.begin() + e - 1);
```

You shouldn’t increment the end() iterator.

Comment: "_You can’t increment the end() iterator._" You can increment it. You just can't dereference it, if it is an iterator outside of the range of [begin; end).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Incrementing an iterator passed `end()` is UB even without dereferencing it if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The more I know. I read that you couldn't increment pointers, if said pointer doesn't point to an array element. But, I was not aware of such restriction on iterators. When looking into it: I could see the pre-condition of InputIterator is that in statement `++it`, `it` must be dereferencable. Hence, you couldn't use it on past-the-end iterator without invoking UB. I, however, didn't see such any pre/post-conditions on `it + n`, in RandomAccessIterator, but "operational semantics" showed, that it should behave as if it was using `++it` under the hood.. Thank you for pointing it out.